# GNU Make v3.82 rebuilds target while v3.81 doesn't

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following makefile code:

```
NAME := test

target1: $(addsuffix .bar,$(NAME))
target2: $(addsuffix .dar,$(NAME))

%.bar: $(INPUT)
    touch $@

%.dar: %.bar
    touch $@
```

The I execute this makefile with GNU Make v3.81 like so:

```
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ rm test.*
removed `test.bar'
removed `test.txt'
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ touch test.txt
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ make target2
touch test.bar
touch test.dar
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ make target2
make: Nothing to be done for `target2'.
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ rm test.bar
removed `test.bar'
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ make target2
make: Nothing to be done for `target2'.
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$
```

As I expect, intermediate file test.bar is not rebuild after removing it because test.dar is still up-to-date. But when I use GNU Make v3.82:

```
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ rm test.*
removed `test.dar'
removed `test.txt'
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ touch test.txt
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ mk82 target2
touch test.bar
touch test.dar
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ mk82 target2
make: Nothing to be done for `target2'.
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ rm test.bar
removed `test.bar'
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$ mk82 target2
touch test.bar
touch test.dar
user@node1:/data/user/Tests/oldfile3$
```

Now when I remove test.bar and call make, it will rebuild test.bar and then test.dar. test.txt is still older than test.dar so why remake test.bar which relies on test.txt? This does not happen if I remove target1 like so:

```
NAME := test

target2: $(addsuffix .dar,$(NAME))

%.bar: $(INPUT)
    touch $@

%.dar: %.bar
    touch $@
```

why does it build target1 when I do not specify it anywhere?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: What does `test.txt` have to do with anything? Are you missing a `INPUT:=test.txt` somewhere?

Comment: To show it uses input files. Input files are never deleted and if input were to be created, then it would also be deleted. I wanted to show that input did not change so test.dar should not be recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.bar` is not an intermediate file, because it's explicitly mentioned as a prerequisite of `target1`.  It doesn't have to be explicitly mentioned only in the set of targets and prerequisites that make decides to build, it only has to be mentioned explicitly *somewhere* in the makefile.

After all, it could be that the next time you'll ask to build `target1` and then make would have to rebuild `test.bar`, when it wouldn't have to if it hadn't been deleted.

ETA: I believe the behavior in GNU make 3.81 is a bug.